# Activerecord-import & serial column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, auto-increment

I am in the process of upgrading a Rails 2.3.4 project to Rails 3.1.1. The old version used ar-extensions to handle a data import. I pulled out ar-extensions and replaced it with activerecord-import, which I understand has exactly the same interfaces.

My code calls looks like this

```
Student.import(columns, values)
```

Both args are valid arrays holding the correct data, but I get a big fat error!

The error stack looks like this:

```
NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.split):
  activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:828:in 'default_sequence_name'
  activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/base.rb:647:in `reset_sequence_name'
  activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/base.rb:643:in `sequence_name'
  activerecord-import (0.2.9) lib/activerecord-import/import.rb:203:in `import'
```

Looking through the code it seems as though Activerecord-import calls activerecord which in turn looks for the name and next value of the Postgres sequence.

So activerecord-import looks for the sequence_name
lib/activerecord-import/import.rb:203

```
# Force the primary key col into the insert if it's not
# on the list and we are using a sequence and stuff a nil
# value for it into each row so the sequencer will fire later
-> if !column_names.include?(primary_key) && sequence_name && connection.prefetch_primary_key?
   column_names << primary_key
   array_of_attributes.each { |a| a << nil }
end
```

It calls active record ...
lib/active_record/base.rb:647:in `reset_sequence_name'

```
# Lazy-set the sequence name to the connection's default. This method
# is only ever called once since set_sequence_name overrides it.
def sequence_name #:nodoc:
->  reset_sequence_name
end

def reset_sequence_name #:nodoc:
  -> default = connection.default_sequence_name(table_name, primary_key)
  set_sequence_name(default)
  default
end
```

The code errors when `serial_sequence` returns nil and `default_sequence_name` tries to split it.

```
lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb

# Returns the sequence name for a table's primary key or some other specified key.
def default_sequence_name(table_name, pk = nil) #:nodoc:
  -> serial_sequence(table_name, pk || 'id').split('.').last
rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
  "#{table_name}_#{pk || 'id'}_seq"
end

def serial_sequence(table, column)
  result = exec_query(<<-eosql, 'SCHEMA', [[nil, table], [nil, column]])
    SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence($1, $2)
  eosql
  result.rows.first.first
end
```

When I execute `pg_get_serial_sequence()` directly against the database I get no value returned:

```
SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('student', 'id')
```

But I can see that in the database there is a sequence called `student_id_seq`

I am using the following versions of Ruby, rails PG etc..

- Rails 3.1.1
- Ruby 1.9.2
- Activerecord-import 0.2.9
- pg 0.12.2
- psql (9.0.5, server 9.1.3)

I have migrated the database from MySQL to PostgreSQL, I don't think this has any bearing on the problem but I thought that I'd better add it for completeness.

I can't work out why this isn't working!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Summary of your description:

- The table `student` exists.
- The column `id` exists.
- The sequence `student_id_seq` exists.
- `pg_get_serial_sequence('student', 'id')` still returns `NULL`.

#### Two possible explanations:

1) The sequence is **not linked** to the column.

Column default and the tie between column and sequence are independent features. The mere existence of a fitting sequence does not mean it does what you presume. If you create a column as `serial` you get the whole package, though. Read [the details in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL).

To fix this (and if you are sure that's how it should be), you can mark the sequence as "owned by" `student.id`:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE student_id_seq OWNED BY student.id;
```

Also check if the column default is set as expected:

```
SELECT column_name, column_default
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_name = 'student'
-- AND    schema = 'your_schema' -- if needed
```

If not, repair:

```
ALTER TABLE student ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('student.id')
```

2) A **mixup** of host address / port / database / schema / capitalization of the table name.

It happens all the time. Make sure you check the same database that your app connects to, With the same user or at least the same [`search_path`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH). Make sure, the objects are in the schema where you expect them and there isn't, for instance, another `student` table in another schema that got mixed up.

Comment: The Sequence was not attached to the column! Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is also covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546850/newly-assigned-sequence-is-not-working, and I put some comments there about why it cropped up as a problem in Rails 3.1.  The short story is that prior to Rails 3.1, when the column-to-sequence mapping was not known, ActiveRecord would fall back on a default string of `tablename_columnname_seq`, but now there is no fallback, so you must explicitly set the ownership in Postgres (as your solution above states).