# Rename nextval('...') in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, ddl, column-defaults

I had a table called `pivot_device_user` and had a sequence on the id as `not null default nextval('pivot_device_user_id_seq'::regclass)`.

Then I decided to rename my table to `pivot_box_user`, but the `nextval(...)` is still `nextval('pivot_device_user_id_seq'::regclass)`.

I'd like to change it to `nextval('pivot_box_user_id_seq'::regclass)`. How do I do this?

Comment: No, because that sequence is actually a permission that is given to the user. So currently the postgres returns an error saying that the user does not have the right permission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you must understand what a `serial` really is:

- [Safely and cleanly rename tables that use serial primary key columns in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649682/safely-and-cleanly-rename-tables-that-use-serial-primary-key-columns-in-postgres/14651788#14651788)
- [Auto increment SQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517)

The column default is not actually stored as text literal. What you see is just the human-readable text representation: `nextval('pivot_device_user_id_seq'::regclass)`

`'pivot_device_user_id_seq'::regclass` is resolved to an `OID` internally ([`regclass`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html) to be precise) - the OID of the underlying sequence - and that's what's actually stored (early binding). If you rename the sequence, its OID remains unchanged. So all you need to do is [rename the sequence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altersequence.html):

```
ALTER SEQUENCE pivot_device_user_id_seq RENAME TO pivot_box_user_id_seq;
```

Check success with:

```
SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('pivot_box_user', 'id');
```

Related:

- [Activerecord-import & serial column in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737270/activerecord-import-postgresql/9746762#9746762)